# React useEffect in AuthProvider in _app.tsx is Triggered Twice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-context

Question:

I'm encountering an unexpected behavior with the useEffect inside an AuthProvider component in my Next.js application's _app.tsx file. The issue seems to be that the useEffect is being triggered twice during the component's lifecycle.

Context:

I have an AuthProvider component that manages authentication state using a useEffect to fetch data from the server when the component mounts. This component is used exclusively within my _app.tsx file. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// _app.tsx

import { AuthProvider } from '@/context/AuthContext';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

```
// AuthProvider.tsx

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { fetchWithBaseUrl } from 'utils/api';

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // ... other state and functions ...

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('AuthProvider useEffect start');
    // ... fetch logic ...
  }, []);

  // ... return statement ...
};

export { AuthProvider };
```

Issue:

The problem I'm facing is that the useEffect inside AuthProvider seems to be triggered twice during the component's lifecycle, which is not the behavior I expected. I've verified this by adding a console.log statement at the start of the useEffect, and I can see the message logged twice in the console during page load.

Attempts:

I've checked for multiple instances of the AuthProvider component in my codebase, but I'm only using it in the _app.tsx file.
I've considered SSR and the initial render differences, but the behavior persists even after the client-side hydration.
I've inspected the network activity using browser dev tools, and I can see the fetch requests being made as expected.
Question:

Can anyone help me understand why the useEffect within AuthProvider is being triggered twice during the component's lifecycle? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. If there's additional information needed, please let me know.

Comment: thanks, `StrictMode renders components twice`