# React useEffect calls fetch function twice despite having specific dependencies

Tags: reactjs

I'm encountering an issue in my React application where the fetch function inside a useEffect hook is being called twice, and I'm struggling to understand why. Here's the relevant code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.userDTO && router.isReady) {
        let url = paymentId ? `user/tickets?paymentId=${paymentId}` : 'user/tickets';
        fetchWithBaseUrl(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.userDTO.token,
            },
        }).then(async (response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                setMyTickets(data);
            }
        });
    }
}, [auth.userDTO, router.isReady]);
```

As you can see, I've defined auth.userDTO and router.isReady as dependencies for the useEffect. However, I've noticed that the fetch function is being called twice under certain circumstances.

I've considered the following:

1. Initial Render: The fetch function is called on the initial render, which is expected behavior.
2. Dependency Changes: If either auth.userDTO or router.isReady changes during the component's lifecycle, the useEffect hook runs again, leading to an additional call to fetch.
   I'm wondering if there's a way to prevent the extra call to fetch while still ensuring that it runs when both auth.userDTO and router.isReady are truthy.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and if so, how did you resolve it? Are there any best practices or optimizations I can apply to avoid this behavior?

Comment: I think you are using React18 and Here is an overview of the reason from here https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#updates-to-strict-mode

Comment: _"Has anyone encountered a similar issue"_ - https://stackoverflow.com/q/76946229/3001761

Answer (score 0):

If React is in dev mode, it will most probably be using Strict Mode, like this:

```
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
```

In Strict Mode, useEffect's will run twice on first render.

This [article](https://byby.dev/useeffect-run-twice) also gives more info on strict mode and how to disable it if you do not want the `useEffect`s to run twice.